# scikit-learn - Prediction model return "wrong" prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have below dataset in a CSV file called `shipments.csv`. The file have >8k rows:

```
| Consignor Code | Consignee Code | Origin | Destination | Carrier Code | 
|----------------|----------------|--------|-------------|--------------| 
| 6403623194     | 6405167792     | DKCPH  | AUMEL       | 6402746389   | 
| 6403623194     | 6403823770     | DKBLL  | CNTSN       | 6402746354   | 
| 6403623194     | 6403823770     | DKBLL  | CNTSN       | 6402746354   | 
| 6403623194     | 6402546085     | DKBLL  | USDEN       | 6402746424   | 
| 6403623194     | 6402546085     | DKBLL  | USDEN       | 6402746424   | 
...
```

I am trying to create a simple model, where I can predict the `Destination` based on the `Consignee Code`.

To do that, I have created below code:

```py
#Load the dataset and remove unwanted columns and NaN values.
dataset = pd.read_csv('shipments_non_empty.csv', header=0, skip_blank_lines=True)
dataset.drop(columns=['Consignor Code','Carrier Code', 'Origin'], inplace=True)
dataset.dropna(subset=['Consignee Code', 'Destination'], inplace=True)

#Treat the Consignee Code as a string
dataset['Consignee Code'] = dataset['Consignee Code'].astype('int64')

#Define our target (what we want to predict) - and remove it from the 
target = dataset.pop('Destination')

#Convert all our data to numeric values, so we can use the .fit function.
#For that, we use LabelEncoder
le_consignee = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_target = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target = le_target.fit_transform(list(target))
dataset['Consignee Code'] = le_consignee.fit_transform(
    list(dataset['Consignee Code']))

# Prepare the dataset.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset, target, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
```

At this point, my dataset (train/test) is ready. I then move on to fit the model and predict on a new input:

```py
# Prepare the model and .fit it.
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make a prediction on the test set.
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Print the accuracy score.
print("The accuracy score of the predicted output is: {}".format(
    accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)))

#Test on a new input.
new_input = ["6402546085"]
fitted_new_input = np.array([le_consignee.transform([new_input[0]])[0]])
new_predictions = model.predict(fitted_new_input.reshape(1, -1))

print(le_target.inverse_transform(new_predictions))
```

The above code will print out below:

```
The accuracy score of the predicted output is: 0.7233265720081136
['SAJED']
```

As you can see, it predicts the destination as "SAJED". I am finding this very odd, as **none** of my dataset, where the `Consignee Code` is `6402546085`, is the destination `SAJED`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have astype(int64) where your comments say as string. is that a mistake?

Comment: @JasonChia That is indeed a mistake! Very good catch. I changed it to `astype(str)` and now it returns `USDEN`

Comment: Does that mean your problem is solved?

Comment: @JasonChia Sorry, yes! Or at least it seems like it. According to my data, `6402546085` is always being sent to destination `USDEN`

Comment: Alright.Good to hear. Good luck to you then :)

Comment: you might want to close/remove the question as it is a typo mistake than has been solved in the comments (new closing vote option: closing>off-topic>typo)